# ansible-playbook shell module doesn't work

Tags: shell, ssh, ansible

I set up a new Ansible project, in which I want to connect to my EC2 machines and run a few commands.

I added my inventory files, and when I test out a simple Ansible command, everything works fine and I get a response.

`ansible all -m shell -a 'uptime'` or `ansible all -m ping` works well and returns the expected output.

However, when I'm trying to run a simple playbook that uses the built-in shell module, it fails.

Ansible playbook command: `ansible-playbook -vvv playbooks/my_playbook.yaml`
Playbook file:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    -   name: Gather EC2 facts
        action: ec2_facts
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
    -   name: my task
        shell: uptime
```

Gathering EC2 facts works well, but the second part of running a shell command fails with the following exception:

```
<1.2.3.4> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: 
fatal: [1.2.3.4]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false
}

MSG:

This module has been removed. The module documentation for Ansible-2.6 may contain hints for porting
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting this exception, as the shell module was never deprecated.
I also don't use Ansible-2.6, I installed Ansible through pip, versions:

```
ansible==2.9.27
ansible-core==2.15.8
```

I tried to change to the command module, which resulted in the same exception, so I suspect it has to do something with my local environment and not with the shell module itself.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you share the log from the beginning of your playbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `ec2_facts` as a module, which has been [deprecated and then removed in Ansible 2.7](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/24389#issuecomment-429196075) (they failed to list it in the documentation though). Try to use [`ec2_metadata_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_metadata_facts_module.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved it and made the second part of running a shell command work as well. The output is weird because the first task of gathering the facts was marked as successful.